# How to scale up Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a application that uses Apache Kafka Streams.
In case of Kafka Consumer, same `consumer.group.id` guarantees that different application in different instances(i.e. different machine) considered as same consumer group.
Is there anything same as `consumer.group.id` in kafka streams? (i.e. when they have `same configuration`, they considered as same streams)

Comment: When I launches applications with same `application.id`, those applications consume same messages. I just want those applications to be a cluster(not consume same messages).

Comment: You should post this as an answer so it can be accepted and voted up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kstreams also have a consumer name in the form of `application.id`.
In addition to the above method of increasing the consumers to scale up, kstreams also have a property of defining the number of threads which will be run by that particular consumer - the property `num.stream.threads` can be given a higher value (default is 1) to increase the number of threads running in each consumer, thereby scaling up the streams application.